# Why signinmanager.passwordsigninasync method return failure all time in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Here is my `Login` method:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       return View(model);
   }
   //This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    //To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
   var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
   switch (result)
   {
       case SignInStatus.Success:
           return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
       case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
           return View("Lockout");
       case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
           return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
       case SignInStatus.Failure:
       default:
           ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
           return View(model);
   }
}
```

Here is my Authorize filter:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    var userEmailId = httpContext.Session["userName"];
    bool authorize = false;
    foreach (var role in allowedroles)
    {
        /* getting user form current context */
        var user = context.employees.Where(m => m.emailId == userEmailId  && m.Role == role);
        if (user.Count() > 0)
        {
            authorize = true; /* return true if Entity has current user(active) with specific role */
        }
    }
    return authorize;
}
```

Here is my action method:

```
[AuthAttribute]
[CustomAuthorize("Admin", "SuperAdmin")]
public ActionResult GetEmployeeList(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
{
    return View(db.GetListviewData().ToList());
}
```

I have try to used the authorize filter to check the user role from the database but when I try to login in my application `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` method returns failure every time.

Please help me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I realized it only occurred after a user changed their email (obviously then UserName no longer equals Email).

Take a look at the signature for PasswordSignInAsync, the 1st parameter is UserName, yet the default code from Visual Studio project templates has what you and I both had, Email.

Change:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

To:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```